# How to filter dataset by job title?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, data-science

I'm trying to extract the company, job description, reviews, and location for positions that are "data scientist" and "senior data scientist" separately. I started by trying to get an output for data scientist but wasn't able to. The dataset has duplicates of both jobs and I'm trying to exact all the instances in which "data scientist" or "senior data scientist" are mentioned.

```
dataset['position']=dataset.position.str.lower()
dataset
        position            company     description      reviews     location
0   data scientist lead     ALS TDI   This position is...  30.0    Atlanta
1   NaN                      xyz        qualified candid.. 4000.0   Texas
2   data scientist           xcv       python desireable..  232.0    toronto
3   data scientist           intel     CS Degree needed..  322145.0   Newyork
4   senior data scientist   amazon     python, excel....   23222.0     montreal
.
.
5000  data scientist/machine  yahoo   sql needed plus...  Nan            Atlanta
```

I'm using the following to create a dataframe that has explicitly the records for positions that says 'data scientist' only and not the variations found in index 0 and 5000.

```
filtered = dataset[dataset['position'].str.contains('data scientist', na=False)]
```

but it doesn't work as it provides all the records in which strings contain "data scientist" including "senior data scientist" and "data scientist/machine"

Comment: You should look at [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: Please post your code attempt as a code block in the question itself and not as an image... but it looks like you need to pass `na=False` to your `.str.contains`...

Comment: @JonClements added code attempt as a code block.

Comment: @Omar then do you want to be using `contains` instead of just checking using `==` ?

Comment: @JonClements I'm now using contains but I'm interested in unique data scientist only not all strings that may contain data scientist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) is used to find values which **contain** a given string.

[`ps.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html), or equivalently the equality operator `==`, is used to find values which **equal** a given string.

[`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) offers a way to query your dataframe via a string.

So you can use one of:

```
filtered = dataset[dataset['position'].eq('data scientist')]
filtered = dataset[dataset['position'] == 'data scientist']
filtered = dataset.query('position == "data scientist"')
```

Comment: are there advantages/disadvantages to using one over the other?

Comment: Most cases, no.